# Opening CSV files from textbox

Tags: vba, excel, csv, userform

I am developing a user form as you can see below 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buDqe.png)

the code in the Browse Button is

```
Private Sub Browse_Click()

    Dim fName As String
        fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV File (*.csv), *.csv", , "Import .CSV File", , False)

    If Not fName = "False" Then
        TextBox1.Value = fName
    End If

End Sub
```

Next step is to choose some of these options and the code behind it is

```
Private Sub Start_Click()

    Dim Actsheet As String
    Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim wkbSourceBook As Workbook
    Dim rngSourceRange As Range
    Dim rngDestination As Range
    Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set rngDestination = wkbCrntWorkBook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A1")


    If myBeforeImprovements = True Then
        Actsheet = "Before "
    ElseIf AfterImprovements = True Then
        Actsheet = "After "
    Else
        MsgBox ("Select Type of Analysis")
        Exit Sub
    End If


    If Westbound = True Then
        Actsheet = Actsheet & "WB"
    ElseIf Northbound = True Then
        Actsheet = Actsheet & "NB"
    ElseIf Eastbound = True Then
        Actsheet = Actsheet & "EB"
    ElseIf Southbound = True Then
        Actsheet = Actsheet & "SB"
    Else
        MsgBox ("Select Traffic Bound")
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

my problem is I can't take the CSV file to its write sheet which are
Before EB
Before WB
Before NB
Before SB
After EB
After WB
After NB
After SB

maybe the following code will refer to the selected CSV file but it gives me an error

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=TextBox1.Text + "," + ComboBox1.Value + ".txt", _
DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `+` with `&` and it'll hopefully work better. The concatenation operator is & in VBA

Comment: Sam, Thank you for your response. I tried & but it didn't work